# Bash: Get number of elements in an array that is the result of an `ls` command? ${#a[@]} doesn't work

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, command-line

I'm getting the 15 most recent `.jpg` or `.png` files from the current directory in an array:

`images=$(ls -1tr *.jpg *.png | tail -n 15)`

It seems to work fine in this case:

`for i in ${images[*]}; do echo "Found this image: $i"; done`

It shows me the 15 lines as:

> Found this image: foo.jpg
>   Found this image: bar.png
>   Found this image: baz.jpg
>   (...etc...)

However, when I try to print the length of the `$images` array like this:

`echo ${#images[@]}`

I always get:

> 1

Despite the fact that there are multiple images found, and the above `for` loop over the `$images` array does indeed shows multiple lines.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the number of elements in the array?

Comment: You didn't define an array; you defined a regular variable with a single string that contains embedded newlines.

Comment: And defining an array this way -- `images=( $(ls -1tr *.jpg *.png | tail -n 15) )` -- can fail, as the command substitution is subject to both word-spilitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/003 (How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly getting the number of elements, and it is indeed 1.

Since you know JS, here's your code in JavaScript to see what's actually happening:

```
// Assign all filenames to a single index
var images = ["foo.jpg\nbar.jpg\nbaz.jpg"]

// Join all the elements on spaces, then split them up on whitespace
var elements = images.join(" ").split(/[ \t\n]/);

for (var i in elements) {
  console.log("Found this image: " + elements[i]);
}
console.log("Array length: " + images.length);
```

Output:

```
Found this image: foo.jpg
Found this image: bar.jpg
Found this image: baz.jpg
Array length: 1
```

Here's what you instead meant to do in Bash:

```
images=( $(ls -1tr *.jpg *.png | tail -n 15) )
for i in "${images[@]}"; do echo "Found this image: $i"; done
echo "${#images[@]}"
```

Parsing `ls` output is considered fragile though: the above code still splits on whitespace, so `My Image.jpg` will turn into `My` and `Image.jpg`.

Sadly, there's no simple, good replacement when you need files sorted by modification date, but this avoids problems when files contain `*` or spaces (Bash 4+):

```
mapfile -t images < <(ls -tr *.jpg *.png | tail -n 15)
for i in "${images[@]}"; do echo "Found this image: $i"; done
echo "${#images[@]}"
```

Comment: Caveat emptor: the last one still fails if file names can contain newlines (which is rare, but worth mentioning for completeness).